# Discord.js removing role

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a mute command using roles but I keep getting the error saying remove role is not a function. Im confused

```js
let mainrole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Verified");
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Muted");


if (!role) return message.reply("Sorry! Couldn't find the mute role.")


let time = args[2];
if (!time) {
    return message.reply("You didnt specify a time!");
}

person.removeRole(mainrole.id)
person.addRole(role.id);


message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`)

setTimeout(function() {

            person.addRole(mainrole.id)
            person.removeRole(role.id);
```

Error: `TypeError: person.removeRole is not a function`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 1):

Since discord.js v12 you need to use [`roles.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) and [`roles.remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove) instead of `addRole()` and `removeRole()`

```js
person.roles.remove(mainrole.id)
person.roles.add(role.id);


message.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${ms(ms(time))}`)

setTimeout(function() {

            person.roles.add(mainrole.id)
            person.roles.remove(role.id);
```